# Get number of rows per length on a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We are refactorizing our database structure.

I would like to know an SQL Script that returns the number of rows with every length for a selected nvarchar column.

Comment: Why must it be a script?

Comment: Select Datalength(Col1) from table1

Comment: It mustn't jarlh, I can use a simple query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can group by length to get that list:

```
SELECT LEN(str_col), COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY LEN(str_col)
```

String function [`LEN(str)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) returns the length of the value in the column. The list will be returned in no particular order.

Comment: I finally used:   SELECT LEN(valor) longitud, COUNT(*) contador
FROM mto_parametro_valor
GROUP BY LEN(valor)
ORDER BY longitud

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do it:

```
SELECT
    Len(RowName) As FieldLength,
    COUNT(*) AS FieldLengthCount
FROM 
    dbo.Table
GROUP BY 
    Len(RowName)
```